# Where does macOS store private SF Symbols? Such as icons on the Control Center?

Tags: font, icon

Where does macOS store it's icons inside Control Center?
For example the Control Center icon itself? Or the new Stage Manager? Or the Screen Mirroring?

[image]

I know for a fact they're not raster icons anymore but Font Icons, they're not in the SF Symbols either, so they must be stored in a private character map?

Can anyone help me find these icons?